# Android OpenIAB purchase Server verify failed

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

We are building an App which using [OpenIAB](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB) to interact with Yandex.Store. On the android client side, we can buy the In-App items successfully, The problem is that always failed to verify the purchase on server side(We have a Spring MVC based web server to verify the purchase), but it can verify success on Android code. Any helps would appreciate. It seems Signature.java in JAVA(JDK) and Android are different.

Following are purchase verification code snippet:

```
public static boolean verifyPurchase(String base64PublicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(signedData) || StringUtils.isEmpty(base64PublicKey) ||
    StringUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {

    logger.info("Purchase verification failed: missing data.");

        return false;

    }

    PublicKey key = Security.generatePublicKey(base64PublicKey);
    return Security.verify(key, signedData, signature);
}


/**
 * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the
 * Base64-encoded public key.
 *
 * @param encodedPublicKey Base64-encoded public key
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if encodedPublicKey is invalid
 */

public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        logger.info("Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        logger.info("Base64 decoding failed.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Verifies that the signature from the server matches the computed
 * signature on the data.  Returns true if the data is correctly signed.
 *
 * @param publicKey public key associated with the developer account
 * @param signedData signed data from server
 * @param signature server signature
 * @return true if the data and signature match
 */
public static boolean verify(PublicKey publicKey, String signedData, String signature) {
    Signature sig;
    try {
        sig = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        sig.initVerify(publicKey);
        sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
        if (!sig.verify(Base64.decode(signature))) {
            logger.info("Signature verification failed.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        logger.info("NoSuchAlgorithmException.");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        logger.info("Invalid key specification.");
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        logger.info("Signature exception.");
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        logger.info("Base64 decoding failed.");
    }
    return false;
}
```